# functionality of local_fiq_enable()

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Came across the function **local_fiq_enable()**

```
 #define local_fiq_enable()  __asm__("cpsie f    @ __stf" : : : "memory", "cc")
```

Couldn't understand what the `__asm__("cpsie f    @ __stf" : : : "memory", "cc")` does.

All I could understand is enables [1st parameter - cpi**e**] something

Comment: Is it the `__asm__` extension in GCC that bothers you? The assembler instruction itself? How `__asm__` handles arguments? Something else? Can you please be more specific. [`__asm__` itself is well documented](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
__asm__("cpsie f    @ __stf" : : : "memory", "cc")
```

is inline assembler.

You didn't specify your architecture (that would be really helpful here, because assembler is different for every CPU instruction set), but this looks ARM-sy:

If that's the case, this enables interrupts. What it really does depends on your device -- not only the ARM generation, but your *actual* piece of silicon. This happens on the interface between the ARM IP core and the "outer world".